# Where should I initialize my switch widget Android

Tags: java, android

I have an options menu in my app, and in that I have an option which opens a dialog box which has some widgets. I am not being able to figure out where should I initialize my widgets so that it doesnt give a null pointer exception.

Where should I put `Switch sw = findViewById(R.id.switch1)` so that i can use `sw.setChecked(<condition gets decided in the code>)` before the dialog box opens.

MainActivity.java:

```java
package com.example
//imports
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.option:
                sw.setChecked(true);
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.show();
            
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Error log when i call sw.setChecked inside OnCreate()

```
-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.PjMathematician.ImgMath, PID: 2395
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.PjMathematician.ImgMath/com.PjMathematician.ImgMath.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3093)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6865)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:4125)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.PjMathematician.ImgMath.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:307)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1231)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2842)
09-04 16:38:48.358 2395 2395 E     AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more
```

This error disappears when I comment out the sw.setChecked(true) statement

Comment: Why not initializing the widgets in onCreate(); ?

Comment: @Ali I am calling them in the onOptionsItemSelected method, will it still work?

Comment: yes it will but will crash when any option will be selected because the views are already been initialized, but on the option selected the overriding method will be called and views will be reinitialized.

Comment: I am not sure that the app will crash or not by reinitialization but to be honest reinitialization of already initialized views is the worst practice.

Comment: @Ali ok, thank you i understand, so what should i do then?

Comment: you want the condition to be in `onOptionMenuSelected()` ?

Comment: @Ali the condition is actually dependent on SharedPreferences

Comment: ok I've just added some changes it will help you out

Comment: @Ali hello there, I appreciate your hardwork but it seems you missed a little detail, I have added an answer which seems to work. **But for all the General situations, your suggestions are very descriptive and clear**

Comment: @Pj30 thanks mate for your appreciation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work, since the Switch view is inside the dialog box, you should get its instance using dialog.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

```java
package com.example
//imports
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.option:
                sw.setChecked(true);
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                Switch sw = dialog.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                sw.setChecked(condition);
                dialog.show();
            
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this.

**Main Activity**

```
 package com.example
//imports
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //initialize the switch here
        Switch sw = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if(sharedPreferenceObj == your logic){
          //your business logic here
        }else{
          //if condition is false then do stuff here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.option:
                sw.setChecked(true);
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.show();
            
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts but it is still giving me the error, infact, in think i am not using Switch correctly, since for instance, `Switch sw = findViewById(R.id.switch1);` `sw.setChecked(true);` if i write these in my OnCreate();, it still gives me error

Comment: @Jack is your activity layout name is **`main`** ? like here
        `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: yes, the activity layout is main.xml in layout folder

Comment: ok try to invalidate and restart, if it does not help then double-check the id of the switch as well you might not be the correct id in the main activity, I am not sure, to be honest

Comment: Oh okay I will do that, thanks alot  again for your efforts